# Multiple link_to methods how to determine which one is clicked in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got multiple link_to methods in my view. Using the remote option true is there any way I can tell which link was clicked in my controllers update action?

Also, specifically I would like my link_to methods to call the update action in my controller which will increment or decrement the instance variable @lang, save the value in the DB, and then redirect back to the show action.

Here is what I have so far in my view file:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">

  <%= @word.english %>, <%= @word.english_to_spanish %>

  <%= link_to "Previous", "/langs/#{@lang - 1}", :method => :put %>
  <%= link_to "Next", "/langs/#{@lang + 1}", :method => :put %>

</div>
```

Here is my langs controller:

```
class LangsController < ApplicationController

      def show

        @word = Lang.find(params[:id])

        @lang = current_user.bookmark #bookmark keeps track in db for what word user is on

      end

      def update

          @lang = @lang - 1
          current_user.bookmark = @lang
          current_user.save
          render 'show'
      end

    end
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine which link was clicked on your controllers update action, you can pass optional parameters:

```
<%= link_to "Previous", user_path(:id => @lang - 1, :option => 'previous'),  :method => :put%>
<%= link_to "Next", user_path(:id => @lang + 1, :option => 'next'),  :method => :put%>
```

Then, in your controller check `params[:option]` value.

---

*Q: would the syntax in the controller be something like if params[:next] or something like if params[:option] == "next")*

Actually, `params[:option] == "next"` is what you need to check the clicked link.
But if you prefer hipster-code style (like I am), you can do a trick:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ..
  def update
    if link_to(:next)
      #'Next' link was clicked
    end
  end

  def link_to(option)
    params[:option] == option.to_s
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Vitalyp. The :option was exactly what I was looking for. Quick follow up though: would the syntax in the controller be something like if params[:next] or something like if params[:option] == "next"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping out a rails noob :)

Comment: Never say you are noob (c: